# PC crashes when I tranfer files from Nexus4

Tags: nexus-4, usb-connection-mode

I have a problem with my Nexus4 stock.

When I connect the smartphone to the pc (both Linux and windows) and I try to transfer files (video and photo) it copy few Mb then it gives me an error and the pc crashes.

I try with both mode connection settings from Nexus4, and I also hard reset it but I do not understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the [unreliable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol#Drawbacks) USB connection to transfer files, I would suggest using Wi-Fi. You can easily create a FTP server on your phone and then access it from Windows Explorer or Linux. You can easily transfer files after that. I would suggest using [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) for this. [Here's](https://seo-michael.co.uk/manage-files-on-android-device-via-pc-using-ftp-on-es-file-explorer/) the tutorial on how to create FTP Server using ES.
Alternatively you can use any other FTP Server apps available in Play Store.
[Servers Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate&hl=en), [FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer&hl=en)
Also [SuperBeam](http://superbe.am/for-pc/) is a great way to transfer files. It has apps for both Windows and Linux. You might want to take a look at it.